# GPU Doesnt allow Boot but does display video

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

im lookin for some help with this gpu I have. Long story short, basically this pc I had before apparently broke with this I mean that the motherboard perhaps died. After this I went and tried my gpu in some friends PC and to his words basically the PC booted up and his bios wasnt locked, frozen or in any boot loop.

The system I have rn and In which im trying the GPU again and not getting it to boot is this:
i5-3470

12gb ram

H61h2-m12 > https://www.ecs.com.tw/es/Product/Motherboard/H61H2-M12_V1.0/specification

EVGA gtx 1060 SSC 3gb

PSU EVGA bronze 500w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERiC4JUX1ko

In this short video I attach, you see basically how it boots with the HDMI port and get to that bios boot loop where you cant even press F2 or Del. Something else to mention is that with DVI port it doesnt display any video. Also I tried other gpu I had around and it did work. (Quadro 600)
Hope u guys can help me solve this or just let me know if I have to bury the GPU :(

Comment: It seems the graphics is too new for the motherboard.

Comment: Do you really think so? Whenever I can im gonna try it in some other moba